# c++ sizeof() not returning correct size

Tags: c++, string, sizeof

I'm trying to get the size of a string in my program, so then I can convert it into a char later using a loop, but the size that the program is returning is 5 numbers lesser than the actual size. Why would this be happening?

```
std::string theFileName = fileNames[ curTab ];
int size = sizeof( theFileName );
```

When debugging my program, it stores this in theFileName:

theFileName = "C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\Untitled.txt"

And this in size:

size = 32

If you count the characters in theFileName, its actually 37. What is causing this to happen? I'm using MS Visual C++ 2010 Express, creating a notepad program.

Comment: Use the `size` function. Look up what `sizeof` does.

Comment: @Vince: What made you think that you can use `sizeof` for that purpose in the first place? Did you read the specification of `sizeof`? Or did you just decide that `sizeof` kinda "sounds right"?

Comment: I'm not sure why I thought of that. I guess I didn't look up the specification for it, which I should have done cause now I seem like an idiot :P

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` tells you the size of the data structure and all its member data. However, a string object will typically store the string data on the heap -- i.e. it's not member data, but the object owns it and stores a pointer to it.

The correct way to get the size of your string object is to call the `size()` or `length()` member function.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is not an array of chars. Is a dynamic array managed by the `std::string` object. `sizeof` returns the size of the specified data type, in the case of string, the pointer to the array plus an amount of statically allocated chars (Thats a common string optimization).

What you should use is the builtin function `size()`, which returns the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the content is determined with

```
theFileName.size()
```

while `sizeof` returns the size of the object `std::string`. The object could, for example, contain a pointer to the location of the content and an unsigned integer to represent the length. `sizeof` would therefore contain the size of one pointer and the unsigned integer. This would not vary if you change the content.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a std::string object is unrelated to the size of the string it contains. Use the std::string member function provided for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is used to calculate the size of any datatype measured in bytes.

The function you have to use in your program is `size`.